# How to remove first occurrence of a specific item from a list of items without using .pop() or .remove()

Tags: python, list

I have a list, let us call it l = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,7]. Given this list l, I am trying to remove the first occurrence of the number 7 without using the .pop() or .remove() built-in functions.

I have tried

```
def remove_item(l, item_to_remove):
  newlst = []
  for item in l:
      if item != item_to_remove:
        newlst.append(item)
  return newlst
```

However, this removes all instances of the item I am trying to remove when in fact I only want to remove the very first instance of that said specific item. Does anyone have some tips on how to accomplish this??

Comment: why can't you use `remove` inbuilt option?

Comment: it was just something that I wanted to try out! I like understanding how these functions work. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 5):

You only need to take care that the removing part of your code doesn't run twice.

```py
lst = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,7]  # [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7]
print(lst)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 7:
        del lst[i]  # [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7]
        break
print(lst)
```

It does exactly the same as the following:

```py
lst = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,7]
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 7:
        lst.pop(i)
        break
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7]
```

as well as this

```py
lst = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,7]
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 7:
        lst.remove(lst[i])
        break
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7]
```

Overview of the used methods:

1. [del list[i]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=del#the-del-statement) - The del statement can also be used to remove slices from a list
2. [list.pop](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20remove#more-on-lists) - remove and return item at index (default last). Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
3. [list.remove](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20remove#more-on-lists) - remove first occurrence of value.Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a little logic to it. I add a looking variable which signifies that we havent found the entry were looking for. Heres the code

```
def remove_item(l, item_to_remove):
newlst = []
looking = True
for item in l:
    if item != item_to_remove or not looking:
        newlst.append(item)
    else:
        looking = False

return newlst

list = [1,3,4,5,6,7,3,10]
print(remove_item(list, 3))
```

which returns [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 10]

Comment: Nice.  May I suggest using a different variable name than 'list'; as you are currently redefining a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

`.index(x)` returns the first index location of `x` within the list, so just delete it.  If `x` is not found, it returns `ValueError`.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7]
val = 7

if val in my_list:
    del my_list[my_list.index(val)]

>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7]
```

> Signature: my_list.index(value, start=0, stop=9223372036854775807, /)
>
> Docstring:
>   Return first index of value.
>
> Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

Answer (score 2):

Very wasteful, but here you go, a solution:

```
def remove_first(sequence, element):
    return sequence[:sequence.index(element)] + sequence[sequence.index(element)+1:]
```

Then you can:

```
>>> remove_first(["a", "b", "a", "c"], "a"):
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

`index` returns the index of the first found occurrence of an element.
The rest is sequence splicing and catenation.

Of course, you could generalize this to `remove(sequence, element, n)` to remove the n-th found element.
EDIT: I just stated falsely that `index` also supports that. Statement removed.

Or you could choose to mutate the input, but for one, returning the output is cleaner, and you could not have a general "sequence" argument, as not all sequences are mutable. See the `tuple` type.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Minor modification to your code,.

I would prefer `remove` but here is your modified code to do the required job

```
def remove_item(l, item_to_remove):
  newlst = []
  for item in l:
      if item != item_to_remove:
        newlst.append(item)
      else:
        return newlst + l[len(newlst) + 1 :]
  return newlst
```

In Python, you can add the lists. Using list comprehensions, you select sub-lists(`l[len(newlst) + 1 :]`).

Testing

```
>>> list = [1,3,4,5,6,7,3,10]
>>> print(remove_item(list, 3))
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10,7]
new_lst = lst[:lst.index(7)] + lst[lst.index(7) + 1:]
new_lst
```

[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7]

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to [CEWeinhauer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58510621/364696), but one which takes advantage of Python features to minimize overhead once we've found the item to remove:

```
def remove_item(l, item_to_remove):
    newlst = []
    liter = iter(l)                 # Make single pass iterator, producing each item once
    for item in liter:
        if item == item_to_remove:  # Found single item to remove, we're done
            break
        newlst.append(item)         # Not found yet
    newlst += liter                 # Quickly consume all elements after removed item without tests
    return newlst
```

The above works with *any* input iterable in a single pass, so it's better if the input might not be a `list` and/or might be huge. But it's admittedly more complex code. The much simpler solution is to just find the element with `index` and remove it. It might be slightly slower in some cases, since it's two `O(n)` steps instead of just one, but it uses C built-ins more, so it's likely to be faster in practice:

```
 def remove_item(l, item_to_remove):
     newlst = list(l)
     del newlst[newlst.index(item_to_remove)]
     return newlst
```